# Overriding devise_helper.rb is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to customize devise error messages. I created a app/helper/devise_helper.rb file as follows:

```
module DeviseHelper

def devise_error_messages!
return "" if resource.errors.empty?

messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                  count: resource.errors.count,
                  resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

html = <<-HTML
<div class= "alert alert-info alert-dismissable"> 
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  #{messages}
</div>
HTML

html.html_safe
  end
end
```

Also i have app/views/layouts/_flashes.html.erb file  :

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <%= content_tag(:p, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
<% end %>
```

I am rendering the above file in my application.html.erb file:

```
 <%= render "layouts/flashes"  %>
```

Still I am getting the devise error messages in plain text in the top left corner of the webpage. Any pointers?

Comment: If you are not running your app in `development` mode, did you restart your app after you have changed the classes?

Comment: Hi Uzbekjon, I am running my app in development, and restarted my app after making the changes. Not working then also.

Comment: Did you look into the source of the generated page. Maybe it is being rendered as you need, but the div is not styled properly?! Can you add the rendered flash message code here please?

Comment: The same div is being used to style other custom messages. The flash message code from the page source: <p class="flash alert">Invalid email or password.</p>

Answer (score 0):

You don't have style/css class in `app/views/layouts/_flashes.html.erb`. You've them in `DeviseHelper#devise_error_messages!` method, but these two are not related. That's why you're not getting it styled.

Wrap you `_flashes.html.erb` partial with some classes, you would be good to go:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <%= content_tag(:p, value, :class => "flash #{key} alert alert-info") %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <%= content_tag(:p, value, :class => "flash alert alert-#{key}") %>
<% end %>
```